# How to call setState() during integration tests?

Tags: flutter, integration-testing

#### Hi, there!

I testing screen which contains GridView with items inside. The GridView is built dynamically based on the data stored in the database. Then in tests I manually add one item to database, after that I want to call `setState()` for showing and checking it. But I have no idea how to do that. Is it real?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you make the `GridView` listen to the add event, so that it got auto refresh whenever there's data change? In that case, you don't need to call `setState()` for the refresh

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use setState() in this case. Use StreamBuilder to show GridView based on data from firebase. Here's a video of how to implement it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkKEWHfy99Y